# Prove that $\;\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left (1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)^{2^n}$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have to prove that the following limit exists:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)^{2^n}$$
I already proved it is strictly increasing, but I also have to prove its bounded. I need help with proving it to be bounded.

Comment: Do you recognise some other, famous limit?

Comment: yes, but we cann't use that. I have to prove its monotone and its bounded, then it has a limit

Comment: You could check out [this page](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/One_Plus_Reciprocal_to_the_Nth).

Comment: Do you know the inequality $\ln(1+x)\lt x$ for all positive $x$?  Your boundedness follows quickly from that.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki how? I don't see how it follows quickly, could you explain?

Comment: @badshah The log of your expression is $2^n \ln (1+\frac{1}{2^n})$; from $\ln(1+x) \lt x$ it then follows that $2^n\ln (1+\frac{1}{2^n})\lt 2^n (\frac{1}{2^n})=1$.  Exponentiating both sides of the inequality (using the monotonicity of exp, essentially) gives you a bound.

Comment: Oke, and why is log(1+x)<x always?

Comment: @Badshah For instance, it's true (with $\leq$ rather than $\lt$) when $x=0$, and since $\frac{d}{dx} \ln(1+x) = \frac{1}{1+x} \lt 1 = \frac{d}{dx} x$ then it's true for all larger $x$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Putting $2^n=r$ , so $r\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$

So, the limit becomes $\;\lim\limits_{r\to \infty}\left(1+\dfrac 1 r\right)^r$

Now, its $(s+1)$th term of in binomial expansion is $$\frac{r(r-1)\cdots(r-s)}{r^s(s!)}=\frac 1{s!}\prod_{0\le t\le s}\left(1-\frac t r\right)$$

As $r\to\infty, (s+1)$ th term becomes  $\dfrac 1{s!}$

$$\lim_{r\to \infty}\left(1+\frac 1 r\right)^r=\sum_{0\le s< \infty}\frac 1{s!}=1+\frac 1 {1!}+\frac 1 {2!}+\cdots>2$$

Now, $3!=1\cdot2\cdot3>1\cdot2\cdot2\implies \dfrac 1{3!}<\dfrac 1{2^2}$

Similarly, $\dfrac 1{4!}<\dfrac 1{2^3}, \dfrac 1{5!}<\dfrac 1{2^4}$

So,

$\begin{align}\sum\limits_{0\le s<\infty}\dfrac 1{s!}<&1+1+\dfrac 1{2}+\dfrac 1{2^3}+\dfrac 1{2^4}+\cdots=\\=&1+\dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac 1 2}=1+2=3\end{align}$

So, $$2<\lim_{r\to \infty}\left(1+\frac 1 r\right)^r<3$$

Comment: I cant use that

Comment: @Badshah, could you please share the reason and tell me which formulae are allowed?

Comment: @Badshah, then lookup a proof for this equivalence and apply it to your problem.

Comment: I have to prove its monotone and its bounded. I also know that 1+k/x >=(1+1/x)^k for k a natural number and x>0

Comment: That's odd. Putting $x = k$ yields $e \le 2$, an apparent contradiction.

Comment: @Badshah the sign in the inequality is reversed. $1 + \frac{k}{x} < (1 + 1/x)^k$ it seems.

Comment: Thanks, this clear and yes, it should be <.

Comment: @Badshah, welcome, did I make any mistake?

Comment: This seems far from being a complete answer by itself; it's missing easily the most important part, that $\lim (1+\frac{1}{r})^r = \sum \frac{1}{s!}$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, could you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Sorry - I should say that that equation is used without any explanation of how it might be derived or where it might come from. _Why_ are the two quantities equal?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, could you please look into the edited  answer?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee That makes it much clearer! +1.

Answer (score 3):

To prove it is bounded, we will exploit the fact $ \ln(1+x) \leq x $. Now, we have

$$ a_n = e^{2^n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)} \leq e^{}  $$

Answer (score 0):

Let's make two steps together, hopefully that should be enough.
Consider $f(x) = (1+1/x)^x$ and it is now sufficient to show that $f(x)$ is bounded as $x \to \infty$.
Let $L(x) = \log f(x) = x \log(1+1/x)$. Now since $\log(x)$ is continuous, it suffices to show that $L(x)$ is bounded as $x \to \infty$. (You could e.g. prove that $L(x) < 3$ for all $x > 1$.)